# how to start a service at program start rather than application start with play framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'd like to start an Akka service on programme start to avoid a race condition. I've tried both the Global and plugin hooks but are called when the application starts after it receives its first web request but not when the programme starts.

Are there any other hooks / configuration options / coding tricks I can use?

I'm using Play 2.2 and Scala

Comment: I guess you are using `play run` command.  This command never `start` the application until the first request receive. If you type `play start` Global, and plugin hook will be executed immedialtly

Comment: Yes that works but I loose dynamic recompilation

Comment: But thanks will do for now

Comment: Dynamic recompilation in Play is supposed for development NOT for production! You can use i.e. Idea 12+ with Play support it has option to open browser each time when you use run config - so it will make at least one request, anyway its still about development